# Files uploaded using http PUT are not of exact size on the server

Tags: java, http, file-upload, put

I am trying to upload files of different MIME types to AWS S3 using the presigned URL.  I am able to see the document on S3 but the content is inappropriate.  It is either 0 bytes or less than the expected size for every file that I am trying.

Here is the code, please let me know what is missing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    URLConnection urlconnection = null;

    try {
        File file = new File(File_Path);

        if (isEncoded == "false") {
            URL obj = new URL(Upload_Url);
            urlconnection = obj.openConnection();
        } else {
            try {
                URI uri = new URI(Upload_Url);
                URL url = uri.toURL();
                urlconnection = url.openConnection();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        urlconnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlconnection.setDoInput(true);

        if (urlconnection instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
            ((HttpURLConnection) urlconnection).setRequestMethod("PUT");
            ((HttpURLConnection) urlconnection).setRequestProperty("Content-Type", Content_Type);
            ((HttpURLConnection) urlconnection).connect();
        }

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlconnection.getOutputStream());
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        int i;
        // read byte by byte until end of stream
        while ((i = bis.read()) > 0) {
            bos.write(i);
        }
        bis.close();
        bos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Is it with content or size ? Any exception ?

Comment: What HTTP status code was returned?

Comment: Size of the file is inappropriate.  Hence, when I download the file, it is corrupted.

Comment: Upload is successful, so I receive 200

Comment: How can you tell what the HTTP status code is with that code?

Comment: Further I am reading the response code and printing it in my test.. Didn't copy that part of the code here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your end-of-stream detection is wrong, thus you're truncating when you see a null byte.

Comment: From the text file uploaded to the server, I see that the content is stopped when it has encountered the below characters: ã™VJŒ/Õ+)™T≤R

V“Q*.I,IU≤RrvT“QJŒ,I8˙¯+8˙Ñ¯+’ˇˇ
a
C¯ôk0
How do I ensure end-of-stream is detected when actually the end of file is reached?

Comment: I tried: while ((i = bis.read()) != -1) {
            bos.write(i);
        }   This solved for text files and I am able to see full content on the file uploaded to server.  But images are still at 0 bytes.  Any help?

Comment: @Jayashree I suggest you retest that. This answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, I am able to upload images as well.  There was an issue with the base image that I was trying to read from.  Thanks for the answer!